# Compare two collections in jhipster

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-security, jhipster

I need to find why contains or equals methods in java doesn't work in my jhipster project? This is inside the UserResource.java

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().contains(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN_N);
```

For that it returns `false` even `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()= [ROLE_ADMIN]` and `AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN_N=[ROLE_ADMIN]`. Method `equals` also doesn't work. So what is the correct way? My jhipster version is 4.8.2.

```
public final class AuthoritiesConstants {

public static final String ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";

public static final String ADMIN_N = "[ROLE_ADMIN]";

}
```

Comment: Authentication.getAuthorities is a collection of GrantedAuthority. It seems that ADMIN_N is a Collection<String> (or a Collection of something else, but your title talks about comparing strings). A collection of GrantedAuthority can't possibly contain a collection of Strings, nor a collection of anything else, nor a String.

Comment: Yeah. may be. Thanks. I will update the title. So how can I compare it?

Comment: I don't know, since you're not saying what ADMIN_N is.

Comment: It's a string variable as defined in the question. (AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN_N=[ROLE_ADMIN])

Comment: Show us the code defining and initializing this constant.

Comment: public static final String ADMIN_N = "[ROLE_ADMIN]";

Comment: OK. Why in hell do you put brackets around your role name? I guess you'll have to remove them, and check if one of the GrantedAuthorities returned by getAuthorities() has an [authority](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html#getAuthority--) equal to "ROLE_ADMIN"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157827/discussion-between-a-wen-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: Since SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities() prints [ROLE_ADMIN] in the console I tried that way also. Because couldn't think it returns a collection.

Comment: You really need to learn to read the javadoc of the classes and methods you're using. Trying random things based on whatsomething prints is not a wise way to program. Especially when dealing with security-related stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with these two :

```
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.isUserInRole(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
```

and :

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAu‌​thorities();
boolean hasRoleAdmin = authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN));
```

Comment: non-static method getAuthorities() cannot be referenced from a static context error was there

Comment: non-static method isUserInRole(String) cannot be referenced from a static context error for other as well.

Comment: What if you change the second option : Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities(); for **Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();**

Comment: Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();

Comment: It works when I changed like that. Earlier instead of authentication I called Authentication which is the interface. but still there is an issue. It will not go inside if (userService.getAuthorities().size() == 1 && userService.getAuthorities().contains(AuthoritiesConstants.Student)) {

Comment: even hasAuthorityMember is true

Comment: May be same contains method issue now for this new issue

Comment: What do you get for userService.getAuthorities().size() and userService.getAuthorities() on debug mode ? And to what equals AuthoritiesConstants.S‌​tudent ?

Comment: ok. Got it already. Delay to see. That was issue of size. For my one it should be 4. I'll check again

Comment: Yeah. that was it. Thank you very much for the support

Comment: Sorry to tell that member can delete any user. I need to restrict it only to student. userService.getAuthorities()  method will return all the roles. So that may be the reason. We have to find another method to get the user where I need to delete. So do u have any idea?